# Android creating a view and positioning it through java

Tags: java, android, view, positioning

so I'm trying to figure out how to create a basic view and position it directly in the center of the screen using java code and not the xml. I've been able to create the view, but I can't seem to get the positioning right, every time I try something it just stays in the top left corner.

Just to clearify what I mean by view, in xml it's just called a view, it does not include text or images or anythign, I just need a square that has a colored background.

Hopefully someone can help me with the steps of creating this properly and positioning it correctly in the center.

Comment: @Prothean Was my solution helpful? Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the view's layout parameters.

Assuming you've initialized your `View` and you're adding it to a `RelativeLayout`, here's how you would accomplish this:

```
View view = // your view
RelativeLayout container = // the container to which the view will be added
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
view.setLayoutParams(params);
container.addView(view);
```

Check out the [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) for more info.